# Arguments not being passed to window.onerror function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an error logging function along with a call to an undefined variable `t`:

```
const errortext = document.getElementById("errortext");

window.addEventListener("error", function (msg, file_loc, line_no) {
  errortext.innerHTML += msg + "&nbsp;" + file_loc + "&nbsp;" + line_no;
});

t
```

It fires, but errortext is this:

```
[object ErrorEvent] undefined undefined
```

My question is, why arguments are not being passed, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: The `window.onerror = function() {};` syntax takes the parameters you're expecting. But when using `addEventListener('error', function() {});`, only an [ErrorEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ErrorEvent) is passed. It's an Object with properties which can be accessed like `error.message`, `error.filename`, etc. Have a look at this [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to the MDN docs on global error handlers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror) it says

> For historical reasons, different arguments are passed to
> window.onerror and element.onerror handlers (as well as on error-type
> window.addEventListener handlers).

Under addEventListener it shows the signature

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(event) { ... })
```

while it looks like onerror gives you the params you are expecting

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) { ... };
```

Comment: Is there any way I could prevent interference between my onerror function and others that may be on a foreign website?

Comment: "Foreign websites" are ran in different sandboxes, so they can't interfere with each other. But if you include external scripts which may be using `window.onerror`, you're right, only one of these event handlers will work (the last one defined, since they overwrite each other). Then just use `addEventListener`, which will just add one on top

Comment: @luekbaja Why not? Of course you are. https://jsfiddle.net/s1qvaepx/